# Why am I getting this error when I use Ember.View.extend?

Tags: ember.js

I'm getting the following error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'extend' of undefined

when I try to use:

Ember.View.extend

I read that Views have been removed, what should I use instead?

Thanks,
Katie.

Comment: yes, Views are removed. Why do you think you need a view? Depending on your use-case you should use different things, but most likely is a component. Also *dont* use the global scope, use `ember-cli`!

Answer (score 1):

`Ember.Views` are deprecated from Ember 2.0. But still it can be used with the support of their `ember-legacy-views` addon. Even this addon will be only compatible for the versions before v2.4.The object `Ember.CoreView` from which `Ember.Views` is extended is also deprecated.

So the best way is to use `Ember.Component`. Like Views, Components are too re-usable and isolated from others with its own context with the template.

Refer for more info on [Ember.View deprecation and steps to migrate from Views to Components](https://www.emberjs.com/deprecations/v1.x/#toc_ember-view)